# Whats the function to translate between two number series with and without zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

There are two number series 
`series 1` : 0 1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 10 11 ...

And the second number series is stripped by zero's
`series 2` : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12

Thus we can see that 12 of `series 2` maps to 10 of `series 1`

I am looking for a formulae that can do such translations for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understanding what you're asking...

Series 1: $$ a_n=n-1 \ for \ n>0 $$

Series 2: $$ a_m=m \ for \ n>0 $$

The translation would  be m=n-1